# Subdividing a chessboard into rectangles

Tags: combinatorics

Astonishingly, I couldn't find a link to this problem:

Take a $n\cdot n$ chessboard and cut it along the grid lines such that each part is rectangular. How many different cut schemes exist?

Example: $2\cdot 2$. 1 scheme with no cuts, 2 schemes with two $1\cdot 2$ rectangles, 4 schemes with one $1\cdot 2$ rectangle, 1 scheme with four $1\cdot 1$ rectangles, total 8. (As you see, symmetry-related schemes are counted each.)

Comment: Do the cuts have to go all the way across an uncut rectangle?

Comment: "Each part is rectangular" with any size ? or all the rectangular pieces have the same size ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: As my example shows, the size may be mixed: One 1*2, two 1*1 I listed as solution.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Pardon my German, I don't understand your question. Nothing can go across an uncut rectangle, otherwise it wouldn't be uncut. Could you reformulate?

Comment: Can you have a tatami mat-like pattern where it is not possible to decompose the subdivision into smaller rectangles along any single cut?

Comment: Ah, I see! You mean e.g. a 3*3 case with one 1*1 in the center and four 1*2 around it, right? Yes, that is perfectly OK. (I think your version even has a special name in math.)